# trying to make width of tinyMCE 3.x floating

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce

We use tinyMCE 3.x in various forms in our site for content entry. All the places it has to have different widths. Earlier with tinyMCE2.0 i had a fix that worked. But since then i replaced it with tinyMCE3.x its not working for me. I trying applying float left to toolbar of tinyMCE it fixed the problem in Mozilla but not in IE7 can somebody help me over this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing tinyMCE, I'm going to go out on a limb and say; toss it in a container and limit the width of that one?